# Writing a Factorial function with Lists

Tags: tail-recursion, invariants, oz, mozart

While I believe I have found a sound algorithm for my function (Factorial) I'm very confused as to why it loops infinitely.
Here's my code :

```
declare
fun{Fact N}
   local M=1 in             %I suppose it loops from here??
      local FactT in        %But the function call starts from here
     fun{FactT N Acc}       % which doesn't include the local declaration of M
        if M==N then
           {Browse M}
           Acc
        else
           %{Browse M}     %displays infinite lines of 1s
           %{Browse N}
           %{Browse Acc}   %They form a continuously growing list of 1s
           {FactT (M+1) (M|Acc)}end
     end
     {FactT N nil}
      end
   end
end

{Browse {Fact 3}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never increment M => `{Fact (M+1) (M|Acc}}` is always `{Fact 2 1|Acc}`

and to make your code more readable, you're not obilged to write

```
fun...
   local ...
   in ...
   end
end
```

you can just write

```
fun...
   ...
in
   ...
end
```

---

### code

Taking those things into account, the most simple factorial function is

```
declare
fun {Fact N}
   fun{Aux N Acc}
      if N=<0 then Acc
      else {Aux N-1 N*Acc}
      end
   end
in
   {Aux N 1}
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion (about the readability) I'll try that in the future.  I'm going to try and rewrite the algorithm with a different idea.

Answer (score 0):

I see program written in this language at the first time, but I think I found the problem.
Function FactT is recursive, right? First argument of FactT is "upper limit", right?
I think the problem is here

```
{FactT (M+1) (M|Acc)}end
```

You're comparing M (which is always equals 1) with M+1 (which is passed as the first argument (N)). This comparing is always "false". For example at first iteration it's 1==N (false), at second iteration it is not 2==N, it's 1==2 (false) and so on.

Sorry for bad explanation. I hope you understand what I wanted to say.

Probably it should look like this:

```
{FactT N ((M+1)|Acc)}end
```

or something.

Comment: Thank you very much for this explanation. I think you pinpointed where the mistake was.
But the suggestion you made can't be applied because the (M+1)|Acc part extends 2 to nil as a list then 2 to 2 and keeps on going. So the arguments don't evolve, which beats the recursion principle.

Comment: @user3078046 as I said, I never saw this language before, so I didn't really know what (M+1)|Acc means ( and didn't want to google it :) ). You're welcome anyway.